# Azure API App can't script deployment

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, web-deployment, azure-api-apps

For Continuous Deployment, i can't seem to figure out how to get build script (Build/Advanced/MSBuild Arguments) in Team Foundation Server to work.

Yes, I used the Azure API Apps (preview) profile option and signed into the azure account - I can publish from there OK. It seems to also use a password that I'm not sure where that is from because when viewing the 'connection' information, it's hidden and it is not available in the `pubxml` when you view it in the solution.

I used to use the following MSBuild arguments for the web application but now if I reference the new Azure publish file, it just doesn't work.

I used to use something like this:

```
/flp:verbosity="diagnostic" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=xxx /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=true /p:UserName="xxxx" /p:Password="xxxx"
```

Overall there is no password available to use for the API apps, so in testing the arguments I removed the `/p` info. I've also made sure that the Azure SDK for VS 2013 was installed on the Team Foundation Server build machine, but that hasn't solved anything. Note when this solution was a Web App, CI and CD was working fine. Right now, if i exclude CD, CI is working fine for the API App.

The verbose log gives me the following errors:

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets
>   (4350): The value for PublishProfile is set to 'xxx', expected to find
>   the file at
>   'C:\Builds\4\Outcomes\yyy\src\zzz\zzz\Properties\PublishProfiles\xxx'
>   but it could not be found.

Now the files do match and the file is located there - I checked in the build folder of the build machine. The reference in the message doesn't refer to the file extension, but it must not need that part.

Anyway, I've been through all this before with the web app deployment, and worst I ever needed to do there was to remove the Team Foundation Server service user workspaces.  I have also deleted all the build folders on the build machine to make sure it was starting fresh. No progress on this problem though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using VSO BuildVNext + MSBuild to deploy API App, here are params for MSBuild:

```
msbuild.exe "[Solution_Name]" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="[Publish_Profile_Name]" /p:UserName="[UserName]" /p:Password="[Password]" /p:platform="any cpu" /p:configuration="debug" /p:VisualStudioVersion="12.0"
```

Those username and password I received during publish on Azure portal (you need to navigate to Api App Host and download publish settings).

Note that it's not secure to store passwords on build server, therefore, it should be used as a temporary solution until Azure Powershell command for Api App deployment is released (which could be used with subscription id and certificate).

Comment: Can you show me how to get password in details? (How to naviage to Api App Host and download publish settings?). Thanks.